# Why do I keep getting a float division by zero in Python?

Tags: python, math

I have written the following code:

```
import math
import scipy

def steffensen(equation, f_prime, x, er, N):
    for i in range(1, N):
        y1 = x
        r = equation(x)
        dx = (-r)/(f_prime(x))
        y2 = y1 + dx
        y3 = y2 + dx
        x = y1-(((y2-y1)**2)/(y3-2*y2+y1))
        z = abs(equation(x))
        print("|f(x)| = %e"%z)
        if z < e:
            print("Converged!")
            break
    return x


#This will be used for testing
def equation(x):
    return math.exp(-x**2 + x)-(0.5*x)

def f_prime(x):
    return (1-2*x)*math.exp(x-(x**2))-0.5

#def main():
x0 = 1
N = 5
er = 1e-6
x = steffensen(equation, f_prime, x0, er, N)
print("Finished!")
```

When compiled, the code returns saying that there is a zero division error: float division by zero on the line that says: x = y1-(((y2-y1)**2)/(y3-2*y2+y1)).   When computed by hand, I don't get 0.  Please help me find the bug.

Comment: Compiled? You mean when ran?

Comment: First part: `y3 + y1 = (y2+dx) + (x) = ((y1+dx)+dx) + x = (((x)+dx)+dx) + x = 2x + 2dx` Second part: `y3 + y1 - 2*y2 = (2x + 2dx) - 2*(y1 + dx) = 2x + 2dx - 2*(x + dx) = 2x + 2dx - 2x - 2dx = 0` Guess you either didn't do it by hand, or you done messed up

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a zero division error because your program divides by zero. The question you should focus on is "how do I figure out what's wrong?" Do it by adding a diagnostic statement just before the line that throws the error. I'd start with this one:

```
    print(i, dx, y1, y2, y3, y3-2*y2+y1)
```

You'll get this output,

> 1 0.3333333333333333 1 1.3333333333333333 1.6666666666666665 0.0

showing that the error occurs on the first pass through the loop (`i == 1`), and that `dx` has the value 1/3. Take it from there, and figure out why your program diverges from the calculation you did by hand.